# Java removing the last string

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have different types of names. Like

```
ABC BCD, EFG HGF, HGF HJK
```

I want to replace the last `,` with `"and"`. So, the format will be like this

```
ABC BCD, EFG HGF & HGF HJK
```

I tried with this

```
names = "Jon Benda, Jon Wetchler, Thomas Leibig "
StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder();
String[] n = getNames.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(n.length);
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    sbd.append(n[i]);
    System.out.print(n[i]);
    if (i < n.length - 3)
        sbd.append(" ");
    else if (i < n.length - 2)
        sbd.append(" & ");
}
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print(sbd);
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your attempt? What does it output?

Comment: Why don't you split the `,`? Then every member in your array will be the full name. Just append all these the way you want and for the last one append it with an &. Or you could replace the last `,` with `and`

Answer (score 23):

Why to over complicate it? You can search for the last index of `,` using [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) and then use [`StringBuilder#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
int lastIdx = names.lastIndexOf(",");
names = new StringBuilder(names).replace(lastIdx, lastIdx+1, "and").toString();
```

Comment: wrote a program for it and meanwhile, you posted a great answer :) upvote from me

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names = "Jon Benda, Jon Wetchler, Thomas Leibig ";
        String newNames = "";
        StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder();
        String[] n = names.split(",");
        System.out.println(n.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {

            if (i == n.length - 1) {
                newNames = newNames + " and " + n[i];
            } else {
                newNames = newNames + n[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newNames);
    }
```

This outputs

```
 Jon Benda  Jon Wetchler  and  Thomas Leibig
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to use RegEx?

What about:

```
int lastIndexOfComa = getNames.lastIndexOf(",");
names = getNames.substring(0, lastIndexOfComa) + " &" + getNames.substring(lastIndexOfComa, getNames.length);
```

?

Comment: I guess @Maroun Maroun got there first, and probably StringBuilder is more efficient...

Comment: The `+` on strings will use a `StringBuilder` under the hood, so I don't know wether there will be much difference in efficiency if any at all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 String name = "ABC BCD, EFG HGF, HGF HJK";
    int index=name.lastIndexOf(",");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(name.substring(0,index));
    sb.append(" and ");
    sb.append(name.substring(index+1,name.length()));
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
name=name.replace(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(",")),"&"+name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(",")+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but this is my contribution:

```
String name = "ABC BCD, EFG HGF, HGF HJK";    
name = name.replaceFirst("(.*),", "$1 &")
```

In this case, is the same use replaceFirst and replaceAll so regular expression only match one time.